# Tracing azure blob storage with open telemetry in golang

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

I have been able to trace mssql and kafka calls in golang using opentelemetry (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/tree/main/specification/trace/semantic_conventions) documentation and send them to azure application insights.

I have not found any examples or documentation how to trace the use of azure blob storage.

I think its possible since is done in dotnet using the azure sdk (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/monitor/Azure.Monitor.OpenTelemetry.Exporter) but I can't figure out what attributes to send. Can anybody point me to an example or some documentation?
Thank you.

Comment: Already an open issue: [Azure-Core: Add OpenTelemetry Tracing Plugin Support for Track2 Go SDKs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/7358)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question but I am thinking about doing the tracing myself as I have done with kafka and mssql in golang. I am not using the azure sdk. My question is what attributes are sent as part of the tracing.